# ui-router freezing when adding either $http or restangular inside resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I got the ui-router/angular unpr issue fixed! Now, I'm wondering why ui-router won't continue once I add $http or restangular call. Maybe my deferred syntax is wrong. Here is the code

```
.state("main", {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        '' : { templateUrl: 'views/main.html' },
        'performance-ui-view@main': {
            templateUrl: 'views/gdreport.html',
            resolve: {
                propertyUserData : function(User, RestFactory, ApiEndpoints, messageService, $q) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    RestFactory.setBaseUrl(ApiEndpoints.DataService);
                    RestFactory.all('gdpermissions').get('access', { 'userresourceid' : userData.resourceId })
                        .then(function(response) {
                            $rootScope.userData.isGlobalAccount = true;
                            User.saveData();
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                            return deferred.promise;
                        }, function(err){
                            // f'ing work around, I've already told 401 to our backend dev
                            $rootScope.userData.isGlobalAccount = false;
                            userData.saveData();
                            deferred.resolve(response);
                        })
                }
            },
            controller : 'GlobalDashboardController'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you forget to return `deferred.promise` from `propertyUserData` resolve function?

Comment: ok, I'll try adding deferred.promise on propertyUserData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the error may be (as it is not mentioned in the question), Seems like you are not returning a promise from the resolve function as you intend to.

```
  propertyUserData : function(User, RestFactory, ApiEndpoints, messageService, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        RestFactory.setBaseUrl(ApiEndpoints.DataService);
        RestFactory.all('gdpermissions').get('access', { 'userresourceid' : userData.resourceId })
            .then(function(response) {
                $rootScope.userData.isGlobalAccount = true;
                User.saveData();
                deferred.resolve(response);

            }, function(response){
                // f'ing work around, I've already told 401 to our backend dev
                $rootScope.userData.isGlobalAccount = false;
                userData.saveData();
                deferred.resolve(response);
            });
      return deferred.promise; //<-- Here
    }
```

But you could just get away with the defered object creation since your api call already returns a promise, just do:

```
  propertyUserData : function(User, RestFactory, ApiEndpoints, messageService, $q) {

        RestFactory.setBaseUrl(ApiEndpoints.DataService);
        return RestFactory.all('gdpermissions').get('access', { 'userresourceid' : userData.resourceId })
            .then(function(response) {
                $rootScope.userData.isGlobalAccount = true;
                User.saveData();
                return response;

            }, function(response){
                $rootScope.userData.isGlobalAccount = false;
                userData.saveData();
                return response;
            });

    }
```

Comment: I fixed my code and it's making an http call now :) However, am I right that if our HTTP call got an error response like 401, resolve will not continue injecting the dependency to our controller?

Comment: 401 is unauthorized so it means your promise will be rejected and since your resolve is rejected it will not instantiate the controller. But you are handling it in your error function. You could actually specifically check for status code 401 and then resolve otherwise reject as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that logic

Comment: There is another error that is not related to this. I'll accept your answer :) Thanks!

Comment: Actually, even if it's 401, it's not executing anything inside my error function. This is weird